# Maximum value of given equation with range of x values

Tags: python

How can I find the maximum value of the following equation: `Fp=(1000 + 9*(x**2) - (183)*x)` Given values of x in the range of (1-10), using python. This is what I have tried already:

```py
L= range(1, 11)
for x in L:
    Fp=(1000 + 9*(x**2) - (183)*x)
    Td=20 - 0.12*(x**2) + (4.2)*x
    print(Fp, Td)
    print(max(Fp))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the set of natural numbers in mind, since you have a small range of numbers to check (only 10 numbers), the first approach would be to check the value of the equation for every number, save it in a list, and find the maximum of that list. Take a look at the code below.

```py
max_list = []
for x in range(1,11):
    Fp = (1000 + 9*(x**2) - (183)*x)
    max_list.append(Fp)

print( max(max_list) )
```

Another more elegant approach is to analyze the equation. Since your *Fp* equation is a **polynomial equation with the positive second power coeficent**, you can assume that either the last element of the range is going to yield the maximum or the first.
So you only need to check those values.

```py
value_range = (1,10)
Fp_first = 1000 + 9*(value_range[0]**2) - (183)*value_range[0]
Fp_last = 1000 + 9*(value_range[1]**2) - (183)*value_range[1]
max_val = max(Fp_first , Fp_last)
```

Comment: +1 for the recommendation of using the structure of the equation. However, note that the coefficient on the linear term is negative so the highest value for the range can be in the beginning, as the results from @user1740577 show.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:-

```
def func(x):
    return 1_000 + 9 * x * x - 183 * x

print(max([func(x) for x in range(1, 11)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're taking the max of a scalar rather than of the values of `Fp` for each of the values of `x`.

For a small range of integer values of `x`, you can iterate over them as you do. And, if you only need the max value,

```
L = range(1, 11)
highest_Fp = 0    # ensured lower than any Fp value
for x in L:
    Fp = (1000 + 9*(x**2) - (183)*x)
    Td = 20 - 0.12*(x**2) + (4.2)*x
    print(Fp, Td)
    if Fp > highest_Fp:
        highest_Fp = Fp
print(highest_Fp)
```